# Responsibilities of CommandBus

Tags: cqrs

Is responsibility of CommandBus both to send and handle commands or just to handle commands?

It’s correct to define interface like below:

```
interface ICommandBus
{
    void SendCommand(ICommand commad);
    void HandleCommand(ICommand commad);
}
```

Is it correct that the interface has both send and handle methods?

Send is responsible to send command over bus or specific recipients

Handle to handle specific command if possible

Answer (score 2):

The Commandbus has the responsibility to dispatch commands to the different corresponding command handlers.  Handling commands is usually not the responsibility of a Commandbus.

Answer (score 0):

The command bus would be responsible for

1. Dispatching commands
2. Registering / discovery of handlers.

The command bus needs to keep a register of handlers that actually handle the commands when they are dispatched, so it needs to know which commands to send to which handlers.

As mentioned in the comments, this would likely be a separate interface, or done through some other discovery style process

Comment: While it is true that the CommandBus has to know the handlers, the Interface segregation principle tells us that a `Register`-method is probably not of interest to clients that simply want to to send commands to the bus. ((In particular, the CommandBus could use other methods or command handler discovery under the hood (e.g., module search), which makes a registration-method on the interface obsolete.))